# PHP - Convert separate day, month, and year to mysql date format

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a day value (1-31), a month value (1-12), and a year value, and i need to save them in my MySQL database date format.

How can i convert those values (3 integers corresponding to the day, month, and year) to a date format to save it in my database?

```
$day = $request->day;     // day(1-31)
$month = $request->month; // month(1-12)
$year = $request->year;  // year

$date = strtotime("$year-$month-$day"); // how to convert above values to a MySQL **date** format?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply concatenate the three values together if you are 100% sure of the values.

```
$mysqlDate = $request->year.'-'.$request->month.'-'.$request->day;
```

You can use `DateTime` class to validate that the integers make a valid date. For example with this code:

```
$mysqlDate = (new \DateTime())->setDate($request->year, $request->month, $request->day)->format('Y-m-d');
```

This will make sure that the date is a proper date and will not cause MySQL errors when you try to enter it into the database.

Then you can simply use this in your prepared statement like this:

```
$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO someTable(someDateColumn) VALUES(?)')
    ->execute([$mysqlDate]);
```

Comment: What if the type is Date instead of DateTime?

Comment: If you have the time part you can also chain call the method [`setTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php), or if you don't have the time part you can leave it as is and the time will be `00:00:00`. The format for the DateTime would be `Y-m-d H:i:s`